# How to send GPS data to server every 5 minutes?

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-agents

I am planning to write WP7 app, which needs to send to server phones GPS position every 5 minutes. Data must be sent to server even if app is not running. One way to do that is to use [Background agents](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7.5-Use-Background-agents.aspx) (I am using 7.5 Mango), but in that case app will send data only every 30 minutes, which is not acceptable in my case.
Is there any other solution?
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not a supported usecase for WP7 apps on Mango. Also, it's important to mention that the location you'll get for [GeoCoordinateWatcher on a background agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28VS.92%29.aspx) is a cached geolocation from approximately the last 15 minutes and not the real-time geolocation.

What exactly are you trying to build if you don't mind me asking? This sounds oddly close to spyware. Even if it's innocuous and meant for a good purpose, I'd be careful walking in any direction that constantly shares GeoLoc with a remote server.

Comment: thanks for your answer. App is really looks like spyware, but it is not, user would turn on or off that feature manually, so he or she would know about that. I also was wondering about battery life. If it get data and send to server too often, battery will die to soon.

Comment: @JustinAngel Google Latitude does just that. The might seem spyware, but Marketplace rules make it necessary for developer to add location on/off option.

Answer (score 3):

Your only choices are sending the data every 5 minutes while application is running ([even when the phone is locked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.applicationidledetectionmode%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)) and/or send the data once every 30 minutes by registering a [PeriodicTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Having said that, I agree with Justin in that what you are describing sounds nefarious.

Comment: Have i missed something? I thought, that we can't change timeout (30 minutes) of PeriodicTask?

Comment: @OlegKalyta - You missed nothing - I was mistaken on the periodic task interval when I wrote this answer.