# WindowsPhone periodict task only works on debug

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

Is there any reason why a periodic task would launch with

```
ScheduledActionService.Add(task);
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(taskname, milis);
```

but once I remove the second line, stop working?

I've waited for **more than an hour** (since the normal time would be 30+ mins), on many attempts fiddling with the code, and **nothing**. Once I uncomment the debug line back in, works as expected.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you implemented the background agent.  See this walkthrough for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: If you set the time of the periodic task lower than 15 minutes it will never trigger, so check that out

Comment: Gambit-the implementation is not exactly like that but has all the necessary steps: remove if already exists, watch for the exceptions, etc.
DVD-Set the time? I can only set an expiration day at two weeks the most. There's no other time property I can set. What are you talking about?

Comment: I think this is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11357109/1300516

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer in the Windows Phone Dev Center forums, on a post from 2011 where several developers complain about the same problem. Until today, no one has posted an answer to why this happens on some equipments (HTC and Nokia), but that a simple reboot should solve the problem, at least temporarily.